# How to do render :new in controller and do not lose params from url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, render

I want to do a `render :new` into my create method from a controller, the problem is, it change the url, and in the url I have a parameter needed to fill the form in my html (like: localhost3000/episodes/new?serie_id=8, I do this with a hidden_field_tag).

My controller:

```
  def new
    @episode= Episode.new
  end

  def create
    # params = { episode: { name: valor, serie_id: valor, ... more} }
    @episode = Episode.new(episode_permits)
    if @episode.save
      redirect_to @episode
    else
      render :new #This render I want to fix
    end
  end
```

My partial _form.html.erb:

```erb
  <%= form_for @chapter do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name%> <!-- I don't want to use required: true -->
        <%= f.hidden_field :serie_id, value: params[:serie_id] %>
  <% end %>
```

If the user press the button which sumbit the form from new to create, if he makes a mistake filling the form, the @episode can't been save and makes the `render :new` and then the url change to localhost3000/episodes/

How can I do for `render :new` do not change the url?

I tried to instead of do `render :new` use `redirect_to new_episode_path(:serie_id => params[:episode][:serie_id])`, but that lost the what user enter to the form and any validates don't show what happened, so that's not an option.

Just little more info about project if it's ambiguous: I'm making a Netflix web to learn Rails, a serie (name) has many episodes and an episode (name, serie_id) belongs to a serie.

Comment: A `render :new` just renders a view, it doesn't change the URL. Perhaps it is just me but I do not understand your question. Can you explain how it changes the URL in your application? And can you please add some code and the steps in which your user uses the views and clicks links to your question to make it clearer?

Comment: Post your controller please, params should not be lost when rendering.

Comment: @Mark I edited the topic, sorry for not being so detailed the first time

Comment: @spickermann edited the topic, sorry for not being so detailed the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails way to do this is by creating a [nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :series do
  resources :episodes, shallow: true
end
```

Run `rails routes` to see the routes output. The key takeaway here is that it creates a `GET /series/:series_id/episodes/new` route and a `POST /series/:series_id/episodes`. This makes the linking between the two resources explicit - and not something tucked away in the body of the request.

In general if you are using a hidden field to pass the id of a resource or a user id you are doing it wrong.

```
class EpisodesController
  before_action :set_series

  # GET /series/1/episodes/new
  def new
    @episode = @series.episodes.new
  end

  # POST /series/1/episodes
  def create
    @episode = @series.episodes.new(episode_params)
    if @episode.save
       redirect_to @episode
    else
       render :new
    end
  end
  # ...
  private 
  def set_series
     @series = Series.find(params[:series_id])
  end

  def episode_params
    params.require(:episode).permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
  end
end
```

To get the form to post to `/series/:serie_id/episodes` instead of `/series` we pass an array:

```
<%= form_for([@series, @episode]) %>
  <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name%>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

> If the user press the button which sumbit the form from new to create,
>   if he makes a mistake filling the form, the @episode can't been save
>   and makes the render :new and then the url change to
>   localhost3000/episodes/

This is a really common beginner hangup thats caused by not understanding how [Rails style REST](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) works

In REST you create a resource by posting to the collection route (`POST /episodes`). This means that the browsers URL is changed by posting the form and this is exactly how it should be.

`render :new` does NOT change the URL. It merely instructs rails to render the *app/views/episodes/new.html.erb* view.

What you then are seeing is the result of performing a non-idempotent action. You should NOT redirect back as its both unnecessary and requires you to place all the params in the query string which is less than ideal.

### PS

You should also note that the [correct singular form of series in English](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/series) is *series* not *serie*. Not sure if rails will properly inflect this but if not you can do so by setting up an inflection.

```
# config/intializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'series', 'series'
en
```

You should then rename the model and associations.

Why does this matter? [The principle of least suprise.](https://medium.com/u2i-blogs/how-violating-the-principle-of-least-surprise-can-introduce-subtle-bugs-to-your-code-8902cc51dc29)

Comment: "Not sure if rails will properly inflect this but if not you can do so by setting up an inflection." rails can and does acknowledge this. e.g. `'series'.singularize #=> "series"` and `series.pluarlize(3) #=> "series"`. Series is actually literally listed in [inflections](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92f567ab30f240a1de152061a6eee76ca6c4da86/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L44)

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky was't able to test it at the time of writing.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! This solved my problem! My bad with that singular form, maybe is obvious, but english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change

```
<%= f.hidden_field :serie_id, value: params[:serie_id] %>
```

to

```
<%= f.hidden_field :serie_id, value: (f.object.serie_id.presence || params[:serie_id]) %>
```

to only fallback to `params[:serie_id]` when the `serie_id` attribute is not set on the chapter already.